# 14.04.4 LTS to 16.04.3 LTS upgrade - ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade

Please I need some help, I barely know and very new Ubuntu user. I'm trying to upgrade from 14.04.4 LTS to 16.04.3 LTS by using

```
do-release-upgrade
```

but it fails and I got that error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 131, in save_system_state
    scrub_sources=True)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 149, in save_state
    self._write_state_installed_pkgs(sourcedir, tar)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 203, in _write_state_installed_pkgs
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 416, in add_to_existing
    self.write(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/problem_report.py", line 369, in write
    block = f.read(1048576)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/xenial", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 239, in main
    save_system_state(logdir)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 131, in save_system_state
    scrub_sources=True)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 149, in save_state
    self._write_state_installed_pkgs(sourcedir, tar)
  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-i_2c0bda/DistUpgrade/apt_clone.py", line 203, in _write_state_installed_pkgs
    import lsb_release
ImportError: No module named 'lsb_release'
=== Command detached from window (Thu Nov  9 11:20:21 2017) ===
```

**What should I do to fix to successful complete upgrade the released?**

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

I did search for *lsb_release* module with `dpkg -S lsb_release | grep python` on my Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and got its package (`lsb-release`). In Trusty it is located in [the same package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=lsb_release.py).

So for me it seems that you should install this package before upgrade with
`sudo apt-get install lsb-release`.